# wordpress menu description css bug- can't align

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, padding

The theme I am working with allows for a description (entered in menu description) under the main menu items. I was able to align the main nav items center without a problem, but I'm trying to align the descriptions under to match with no luck. Because the items all have different character lengths this isn't something I am able to solve with padding adjustments.

Here is the navigation: http://screencast.com/t/F7h1Sp0tk

The CSS exists in two areas, but I will happily pastebin both in full if or anything else needed.

Thank you very much.

Description:

```
span.descmenu {
font-size:12px; 
color:#989797;
padding: 0.85em 40px 0.7em 25px;
```

Main nav:

```
/*Top level menu link items style*/
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a{
  display:block;
  width:80px;
  padding:4px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 10px;
  outline: none;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#7c7c7c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `margin:auto 0;` or `text-align:center;` for `span.descmenu`?

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I have with no luck, hence my confusion.

Comment: @Alex Can you provide a demo of the navigation bar (http://jsfiddle.net) or at least some HTML?

Comment: @Alex Perfect! Removing the padding from `span.descmenu` and applying `text-align:center` to `.jqueryslidemenu ul li` will center the text for you.

Comment: Looking at Safari, it is actually not working here. I think I can fix this with padding? http://screencast.com/t/UiV6QrSi

Comment: @Alex actually it seems a tag is missing or something like that... it seems to have lost the fancy text styling of the others, so that would be my guess.  (note: you may also consider using `&nbsp;` for the description text of the menu items that don't have a description)